# Ionic App on Android Marshmallow repeatedly asking for permission, even after granting it

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, android-permissions

Whenever I try to select an image from my gallery the permission window pops up, asking if the app should be allowed to access my media storage.
After allowing it everything works fine. The next time I want to select an image from my gallery however, the app asks for the same permission again.

Here are the options for my cordova camera plugin:

```
image_options = {
    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
    sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
    correctOrientation: true,
    cameraDirection: 0,
    allowEdit: true,
    encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG
  };
```

Here is the (generated) AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="10000" android:versionName="1.0.0" package="com.mycompany.myapp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true">
    <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <service android:name="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.background.ForegroundService" />
</application>
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="23" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
</manifest>
```

I have ensured that in the settings the app also is allowed to access "Storage".

Is there anything obvious I might be doing wrong?

Comment: For Andorid 6.0 you have to get runtime permission from user only deceleraing them manifest is not enough.

Comment: @Sohail I know. And afaik ionic should handle that itself. As I said the user is asked f he wants to grant thte permission. The problem is that the app doesn't seem to remember that.

Comment: @TinoA. if possible, you can load the project on github so that we can have a look at the issue and simulate

Comment: @Gandhi Sorry, not possible, since its a corporate app ;)

Comment: @TinoA. Really sorry Tino. Without code, we really cant nail the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After days of googling and trying stuff I finally solved the problem by manually adding the CAMERA permission to the android manifest.
First of all I was under the impression that the complete manifest is created on the ionic build/run. Secondly its a bit strange I had to add the camera permission to get the storage permission to work, especially since taking photos was no problem.